# How to expose yaml endpoint in NSwag?

Tags: yaml, nswag

I need to expose the schema definition of API (.net core 2.2) in Yaml not JSON. I'm using NSwag. I found package NSwag.Core.Yaml https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSwag.Core.Yaml/
But I have no idea how I should use it. In Shwasbuckle things are pretty straightforward. Everything you have to do is change the extension to yaml, like this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
 c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml", "My API V1");
});
```

What should I do using NSwag?

Answer (score 1):

Will be supported in next NSwag version:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2331